# What is the difference between "sich amüsieren" and "Spaß machen"?

Tags: verb, verb-choice, verb-usage

Yesterday we drove to the beach and had fun.

> Gestern sind wir an den Strand gefahren und wir haben uns amüsiert.

Does "sich amüsieren" fit in this context? Can I also use "Spaß machen"? Does "sich amüsieren" have a higher degree in meaning than "Spaß machen"? What is the difference between "sich amüsieren" and "Spaß machen"?

Comment: Are you sure that you meant `Spaß machen` instead of `Spaß haben`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Für mich klingt "sich amüsieren" etwas abgehobener, während "Spaß machen" verbreiteter ist.

Ich würde "sich amüsieren" nicht für aktive Dinge verwenden. Man kann sich im Theater als Zuschauer amüsieren (passiv), aber ich würde als Schauspieler sagen "mir macht Theater spielen Spaß", nicht "ich amüsiere mich beim Theater spielen".

Allgemein kann man den Englischen Ausdruck "to have fun" nicht immer direkt als "Spaß haben" oder "Spaß machen" übersetzen. Du kannst sagen "Wir haben am Strand Volleyball gepsielt, haben Sandburgen gebaut, sind schwimmen gegangen -- alles das hat viel Spaß gemacht", aber "Wir sind an den Strand gefahren und hatten Spaß" würde man im Deutschen nicht sagen.

Comment: bzw, man könnte es im Deutschen zwar sagen, aber die Bedeutung wäre eine deutlich andere,.,,

Comment: "Wir hatten gestern viel Spaß am Strand" - das kann man schon sagen.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, "Spaß machen" and "Spaß haben" are two different expressions, the latter simply (and literally) meaning to have fun, while the former can also mean "to fool around". 
I think you can only use it in the passive sense "das macht Spaß, das hat Spaß gemacht" (that is/was fun) or as a general expression "Skifahren macht Spaß" (skiing is fun).

Sich amüsieren is of a higher register (much like "to amuse oneself", I should think) and consequently not commonly used in everyday speech.

> "Wir sind an den Strand gefahren und hatten Spaß" würde man im Deutschen nicht sagen.

Robert has a point there. If I may suggest another way of putting it, consider "das war lustig" (that was fun). The following example sounds good to me (dissenting opinions?) :

> Wir haben den Tag am Strand verbracht und es war sehr lustig.

Answer (score 0):

"Sich amüsieren" (sometimes with the adverb "köstlich" which in this situation does not mean "delicious" but "delightfully" -> "sich köstlich amüsieren") is normally used in more formal texts and in higher society. It is more common in older works (translations of shakespeare and others).

With this background, it is totally viable in this context and i really enjoy using "old words". Being eloquent does not necessarily mean that you're being a douche or a snob and you should always consider who you're talking to. When learning basic german you should rather use "Spaß haben" as explained by the other answers, since "haben" is easy to use as a verb.

Additionally, i agree with Robert that "sich amüsieren" is rather passive when compared with "Spaß haben", although that is not a requirement.